# Python - Relative import does not work

Tags: python, relative-path, python-packaging

My project structure:

```
project1/
    __init__.py
    main/
        __init__.py
        {main}.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        subA/
            __init__.py
            {moduleA}.py 
                class {A_class}
            file3.py
            file4.py
        subB/
            __init__.py
            {moduleB}.py
            file5.py
            file6.py
```

I want to import {muduleA}.py in {moduleB}.py. Why cannot do this attempt?

in {moduleB}.py...

```
from project1.subA import {moduleA}
```

(not work as well followings..)

```
from ..subA import {moduleA}             
from ..subA.{moduleA} import {A_class}   
from project1.subA.{moduleA} import {A_class}
import project1.subA.{moduleA}.{A_class}
```

Comment: try `from project1.main.subA.moduleA import A_class`.. things in your example reside in an inner package called `main`

Answer (score 0):

solved as following

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../..'))

import project1.subA.moduleA.A_class
from project1.subA.moduleA import A_class
```

It will be better to import module explicitly to avoid confusing in the future.